# How to restore a build definition in tfs 2012 using Laika42 Build Definition Extension tool?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, build-definition

A few days ago i asked a question, about how to see the modification of a build definition in tfs 2012. I found out, there is no way by default in VS to do this and i also got a link from this tool in the vsgallery:

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ec36f618-d122-48a3-8236-7d9cd19791ee

My question is how to restore a build definition using this tool? I don't see any menupoint 'Restore' in the context menu of any build definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to restore a definition to a previous state, you'll have to do it through a Source Control checkin first:

1. Right-click definition -> View history...
2. Rollback the definition to the desired state, and checkin.
3. Right-click definition -> Update from Source Control.

Answer (score 0):

Right click your build defnition and choose update from source control.

Reference : http://www.laika42.com/Portals/0/Dcoumentation/BuildDefinitionExtension.pdf#page7